# Programmatically set R.ID

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I downloaded a [class](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap) from [Catch The Cows](http://catchthecows.com/?p=113), it is akin to a Google Map object or at least that is what I am using it for.

It parses an XML file which lists the areas of the screen that should be touchable, and then creates them with this method.
**This is here for context, I have commented out some parts of code, and added my own to try and resolve my issue**

```
private Area addShape( String shape, String name, String coords, String id) {   
        Log.v("IDS:", "id was "+id);
        Area a = null;
        String rid = id.replace("@+id/", "");
        Log.v("IDS:", "rid was "+rid);

        // Generate a new ID for the area.
        int _id = 1;
        View vi = findViewById(_id);
        while (vi!=null) {
            _id++;
            vi = findViewById(_id);
        }

                //View.generateViewId(); //=0;
        Log.v("IDS:", "After conversion final time "+_id);
        /*
        try {
            Class<R.id> res = R.id.class;
            Field field = res.getField(rid);    // eg. rid = area10
            _id = field.getInt(null);
            Log.v("IDS:", "After conversion "+_id);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           _id = 0;
           Log.e("Exception ",e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            Log.v("IDS:", "After conversion final time "+_id);
        }
        */
        if (_id != 0) {
            if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("rect")) {
                String[] v = coords.split(",");
                if (v.length == 4) {
                    a = new RectArea(_id, name, Float.parseFloat(v[0]),
                            Float.parseFloat(v[1]),
                            Float.parseFloat(v[2]),
                            Float.parseFloat(v[3]));
                }
            } 
            if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {
                String[] v = coords.split(",");
                if (v.length == 3) {
                    a = new CircleArea(_id,name, Float.parseFloat(v[0]),
                            Float.parseFloat(v[1]),
                            Float.parseFloat(v[2])
                            );
                }
            } 
            if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("poly")) {               
                a = new PolyArea(_id,name, coords);                     
            } 
            if (a != null) {
                addArea(a);
            }
        } else {
            Log.v("Loading ID: ","_id was 0");
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Unfortunately nothing was rendering on the screen, and this was because _id = 0. This should be changed with this bit of code:

```
   try {
                Class<R.id> res = R.id.class;
                Field field = res.getField(rid);    // eg. rid = area10
                _id = field.getInt(null);
            }
```

How ever I am not sure what it does to try and debug it, can anyone explain what this snippet is doing?

Comment: Well, personally, that code is so poorly formatted I find it hard to read, much less figure out what it's supposed to do.  Please give us a chance by formatting it correctly.

Comment: Done already - I had hit block comment rather than Code section by accident.

Comment: In the `Resources` class you have the `getIdentifier()` method with which you can get the `id` "by name": `getIdentifier("id", "area10", context.getPackage())`.

Comment: The problem is the areas do not exist in R.ID as they are within the parent ImageMap object. They are an abstract object if you will, when the user touches the screen it works out whether the touch was in the bounds of an "Area" but the onCLickEvent was actually ImageMap.OnClick().

Comment: Change your xml file to give ids like `id="@+id/z1"` and not simply a number(like now `id="@+id/1"`) because the system will not be able to parse/generate those in a field name(in java you can't have a variable name starting with a number).

Comment: Perfect - I now have all my areas rendering. I had done that to try and resolve another issue which seems to have gone away of its own accord, so I shall take the small victory.

Comment: Still, are you able to explain what the code within the try-catch statement is doing?

Comment: The last piece of code? It's using reflection to get the value of a field from the `R.id` class.

Answer (score 1):

R is a Read-Only class. It is generate at compile time and You should not use reflection to modify its field. Also you should avoid reflection to access the fields values. You should use the official API.

The comment at the first row of the class is

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY. */
```

Comment: This is code from the class I downloaded, it doesn't work. What I am trying to work out is what it is actually doing so that I can redo it.

Comment: what do you want achieve